# Are there Content Type case naming standards?

Tags: azure, content-type, mime, owasp, web-application-firewall

I'm currently having an issue with the Azure WAF, where it flags an issue with a content type of "application/json". After investigation by Microsoft support, it appears that the OWASP core rule set v3.1 may have an issue with the case used in the web portal.

The page header shows the Content-Type as "Application/Json" and after testing it seems changing this to "application/json" allows the test page to work.

My query is, is there any reference to a standard for naming content types in terms of case formatting?

I've gone to the [IANA Media Types](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#application) and it does indeed list it as "application/json"

Following on from that it shows it was registered under [RFC4627](https://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc4627), in turn obsoleted by [RFC7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc7159), which in turn was obsoleted by [RFC8259](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259.html). In each case "application/json" was used.

Unless I've missed it, is there a standard on how the MIME type should be formatted? I haven't done any web development courses so unsure of standards/best practice.

Comment: Read [this](https://dev.w3.org/html5/cts/html5-type-sniffing.html#content-type-sniffing), specifically #2 on the list: *Let official type be the type given by the Content-Type metadata for the resource (in lowercase , ignoring any parameters). If there is no such type, jump to the unknown type step below.* So, if it's not lowercase, it is considered "unknown type".

Answer (score 1):

MIME types are case insensitive. Refer the RFC2045 [section 5.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#section-5.1)